# WebSockets: Reject handshake for wrong protocol used by client (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a very basic websocket server / client in JS:

**Server:**

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({port: 3300});

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
});
```

**Client:**

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://example.com/socket', ['appProtocol']);
```

I want to reject the connection with the server when the Client is not using the 
*'appProtocol'* protocol.

I feel like this should be pretty easy, still I cant find anything and cant get it done by myself. Any help is highly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I found a solution that works for me:

**Server:**

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer();
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({noServer: true});

wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
    console.log('Opened Connection with URL ' + req.url.substr(1));
    ws.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Closed Connection with URL ' + req.url.substr(1));
    });
});

server.on('upgrade', (request, socket, head) => {
    if (request.headers['sec-websocket-protocol'] === 'appProtocol') {
        wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) => {
            wss.emit('connection', ws, request);
        })
    } else {
        socket.destroy();
    }
});

server.listen(3300);
```